# How to split a wav file in C++?

Tags: c++, split, wav

So I googled a bit and I couldn't find anything on this topic. I want to split a wav file in half. I have the miliseconds already I just need to create a new wav file with the data from the original 1.

Do I need to download any library? Or something?

Thank you

Comment: yes, you have to. `wav` is a container format, and can contain pretty much any audio format you care to think of. you cannot simply split it down the middle, because you'll just corrupt the first half by splitting a block in the middle somewhere, and the second half won't have any of the necessary headers.

Comment: Do you know how to read a WAV file? Do you know how to extract the sound data? Do you know how to write a WAV file? If the answer to any of those questions is "no", then yes you might need a library. Which library? I don't know, there are many, and asking that here is off topic (please read the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), if you haven't done that yet).

Comment: Given the top answer, I disagree with the close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just reading a uncompressed wave file format [Microsoft/IBM format], it's very easy to parse the file by yourself byte-by-byte... you will have fun. The format is very simple.

I suggest you to use this tool to open the WAV file and easily read all the structures inside.
http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/

You may identify each structure just by reading this:
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

This uncompressed WAVE format is just the "bitmap equivalent for sound"... it's pretty much a big grid describing "points over the time" that connected represents the sound wave.

If you are used with parsing binary files, you will get a couple hours to do that... otherwise it's a good chance to learn! ;-)

Or, of course... you can always use a library such as FFmpeg that does the "low level stuff" for you...

Comment: Hi, would you please please help me in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303369/how-to-delete-some-parts-of-a-recorded-file-with-winmm)?

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg helps you. It virtually do everything related to video and audio! Also take a look at [CWave](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29676/CWave-A-Simple-C-Class-to-Manipulate-WAV-Files).

Comment: hi, do you know `CWave` project? can you help me on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303369/how-to-delete-some-parts-of-a-recorded-file-with-winmm)?